# How to connect google sheet as a external database for Wix

Tags: javascript, html, web, velo

https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-adding-and-deleting-an-external-database-collection

> In the Add External Database Collections screen:
>
> 1. Give your namespace for the collections a name
> 2. Enter your SPI's endpoint URL
> 3. Add any necessary connection data to the Configuration (ex: user name, password, secret key)

What is SPI? And what is Google sheet's SPI?

Answer (score 0):

You should have follow the [link present on SPI](https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-working-with-external-database-collections) which could have told you it's a Service Provider Interface (SPI).

You'll probably figure out what is google sheet's SPI in the context of WIX when you'll read carefully the documentation.

Comment: I don't understand any JavaScript

Comment: What you're trying to achieve (using Corvid I presume) doesn't seem to have any Javascript knowledge requirement but still some tenacity to get it work with some general web development knowledge and patience to read the documentation.